# Can git push references outside 'refs/' dir?

Tags: git

**Context**

We have a regular `master` production branch, and feature branches forking out, which are then merged when validated.

I was looking for a way to delete old feature branches, but keep a track that `feature/gizmo` pointed to commit `ea33ffc2` when it was merged.

We keep the default commit message when merging, so one way is to dig through `git log` to find the name back ; I was wondering if I could somehow keep an explicit ref, which would not clobber the output of `git log --decorate` or `gitk` or `gitg` or ...

I was thinking about creating references *outside* the regular `.git/refs/` directory, e.g :

```
git update-ref history/feature/gizmo feature/gizmo
git branch -d feature/gizmo
```

but I couldn't find a way to push references stored in `.git/histroy/` back to `origin`.

**Question**

Is there a way to push references living outside of `refs/` to a remote repository ?

Comment: Couldn't you use [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) for that?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: I was looking for a way to keep refs that do not show up in regular git tools

Comment: I see. You want to be able to find out which commit a feature branch pointed to when it was merged into `master`, correct?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio : exactly

Comment: Maybe using `git notes` is what called for instead? It allows attaching arbitrary notes to arbitrary commits.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't push references outside of the `refs` directory.

However, you can answer the question of *which was the last commit in `feature` before it was merged into `master`* by running this command:

```
git rev-list --merges master | xargs -i sh -c \
'git merge-base -- is-ancestor {}^2 feature && git show {}^2'
```

Let's break it down:

1. `git rev-list --merges master` lists the SHA-1 hashes of the *merge commits* reachable from `master`
2. `xargs -i sh -c` for each of these hashes run the following command
3. `git merge-base -- is-ancestor {}^2 feature` determines whether the *second parent* (referenced with `^2`) of the merge commit is an ancestor of the `feature` branch. In other words, did this merge commit come from `feature`?
4. `&& git show {}^2` If yes, then show the metadata and patch of that commit. If you want a more concise output, you can run `git show --oneline --no-patch {}^2` instead

If you're going to run this multiple times, you could easily put it in a shell script or even an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).